# How to get the current user from a Lambda resolver in AWS Amplify (GraphQL api and NodeJS Lambda)?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I have a graphql Api and added a lambda function to resolve a mutation.

```
type Mutation {
  addTeamMember(email: String!, teamId:ID!): String @function(name: "add-team-member-${env}")
}
```

From the lambda I want to retrieve the authenticated user that sent the request to perform additional validations, ¿How to retrieve it from the request information?

**strong text**

Answer (score 4):

I printed the contents of the first lambda parameter and found it:

Access it with:

```
event.identity.username
```

Answer (score 0):

To access `event.identity` in lambda resolver, we need to configure the request mapping template as below.

```
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Invoke",
  "payload": {
        "args": $utils.toJson($context.args),
        "identity":  $utils.toJson($context.identity)
    }
}
```

Note:
The identity field isn't populated if you use API_KEY authorization.

References:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-identity